# JS аудиоплеер: баг в андроид

Tags: javascript, android

```html
<button onclick='playPause()'><i aria-hidden='true' id='myicon'/></button>
<button onclick='player.volume = Math.min(player.volume * 1.2, 1)'><font size='+1'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-volume-up'/></font></button>
<button onclick='player.volume /= 1.2'><font size='+1'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-volume-down'/></font></button>
```

Есть работающий аудиоплеер на JS. Всё работает, как положено (в десктопе), но: андроид в упор "не видит" предустановленную громкость (0.2) и запускает громкость выше (по ощущениям - 0.5). А при первом нажатии на volume up (+ громкости) вместо увеличения звука производит выполнение заданного значения: сбрасывает звук на 0.2. Далее всё работает, как надо. Баг происзодит только при первом пуске. И только в андроид. Где ошибка?

```js
<script>
var mysrc = &quot;http://радиостанция.mp3&quot;;
var player = new Audio(mysrc); 
var myicon = document.getElementById(&quot;myicon&quot;);
var current_volume = player.volume = 0.2;
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ){
 myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-play&quot;;
}else{
 myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw&quot;;
 player.addEventListener(&#39;loadeddata&#39;, function(){
  myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-play&quot;;
 }, false);
}
function playPause(){
 if(player.paused){
  player.play();
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw&quot;; 
   setTimeout(function(){
    myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-pause&quot;;
    player.volume = current_volume;
   }, 3000);
  }else{
   myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-pause&quot;; 
  }
 }else if(player.muted==true){
  player.muted=false;
  player.volume = current_volume;
  myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-pause&quot;; 
 }else{
  current_volume = player.volume;
  player.muted=true;
  myicon.className = &quot;fa fa-play&quot;; 
 } 
} 
</script>
```